# connection with db2 server using golang using windows

Tags: go, db2

I'm trying to make connection to a Db2 database using golang. I'm using [package](https://bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli) to make connection and using the Db2 client called `v10.1fp6_ntx64_odbc_cli`.

However when I see the instruction on phiggins package it suggest to rebuild package after providing few environment variables

```
#!/bin/bash

 DB2HOME=$HOME/sqllib
 export CGO_LDFLAGS=-L$DB2HOME/lib
 export CGO_CFLAGS=-I$DB2HOME/include

 go build .
```

I'm new to golang and not sure how to perform this on Windows. I tried doing it using setting up environment variable but does not work. getting error

> panic: Failed to load db2cli64.dll: The specified module could not be found.
>   goroutine 1 [running]:
>       syscall.(*LazyProc).mustFind(0xc000060270)
>        C:/Go/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:280 +0x5f
>       syscall.(*LazyProc).Addr(0xc000060270, 0x64)
>        C:/Go/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:287 +0x32
>       bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli/api.SQLAllocHandle(0x4f0001, 0x0, 0xc000071ef8, 0xc000071f00)
>        C:/Users/myuser/go/src/bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli/api/zapi_windows.go:44 +0x34
>          bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli.initDriver(0x0, 0x0)
>        C:/Users/myuser/go/src/bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli/driver.go:26 +0x57
>                bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli.init.0()
>        C:/Users/myuser/go/src/bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli/driver.go:52 +0x29
>          exit status 2

Please help me to solve this , Looking to connect to a Db2 database using golang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps let me connect to Db2 from golang on Windows7 pro x64. 
Your mileage may vary.

I Used a recent "Db2 Runtime Client" package for Windows x64 downloadable from IBM website (in my case that was version 11.1.3.3b) and the filename I downloaded was `v11.1.3fp3b_ntx64_rtcl.exe`

This is installed locally at location `"c:\Program Files\IBM\sqllib"` location (default).

I have already a working gcc installed on Windows7 for other projects (it may be from minGW).

I verified in a db2cmd.exe window that I can successfully connect via the CLP (which uses CLI) to the database of interest, using a specific port number and specific credentials. This way I know that the Db2-client is installed properly, and the Db2-server is running, the database is available, and credentials and port are all OK.

Running as local administrator, Installed go for Windows from msi file downloaded from golang.org/dl to default location `c:\go`.

Downloaded  `phiggins-db2cli-*.zip` from https://bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli

Created local directory: `mkdir %userprofile%\go\src\bitbucket.org\phiggins\db2cli`

Unzipped contents of the phiggins-db2cli-*.zip into `%userprofile%\go\src\bitbucket.org\phiggins\db2cli`

In a db2cmd.exe window running as Adminstrator:

```
cd %userprofile%\go\src\bitbucket.org\phiggins\db2cli
```

Created a batch file `buildgo.bat` with the following contents:

```
set DB2HOME="C:\program files\ibm\sqllib"

set CGO_LDFLAGS=-L"C:\Program Files\IBM\sqllib\lib"

set CGO_CFLAGS=-I"C:\Program Files\IBM\sqllib\include"

go build .
```

In a db2cmd window running as administrator, ran the batchfile, it completed without errors or messages with errorlevel 0.

In the same db2cmd window, created a file containing the sample program shown at https://bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli

The file I created was called `testgo.go`

I then execute the sample program:

```
go run testgo.co -conn DATABASE=sample;HOSTNAME=whatever;PORT=60000;UID=whatever;PWD=whatever;
```

--> successfully get the result set on screen

Comment: Thanks mao for the response, i tried with these changes. however there is some conflict between  package import and my mail class import so i had to remove phiggins import "bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli" from my class. After that getting this issue if you know          sql: unknown driver "db2-cli" (forgotten import?)

Comment: Too vague. Edit your question to fully describe your environment (versions of all components), and exactly what steps you took, and whether you proved the Db2 client was working correctly before you try go with phiggins db2cli, and whether you used *exactly* the sample program given by phiggins.

Comment: I could connect to my local db2 instance after redoing above configuration. For remote connection i am getting license issue, but that is not related to this. Thanks a lot mao.

Comment: Well done. Mark the answer as correct if it helped you. If the remote database runs on Z/OS or i-Series you will need to add the relevant licence file to your Db2 client.